# AutoHotKey If Key pressed while win11 TaskView is open syntax

Tags: windows, themes, customization, autohotkey, gnome

I've recently been using Gnome 41.5 and fell in love with the way the Activities menu works
So I am trying to use AHK to create a script that when I press the windows key it opens Task View - then if Task View is open and I start to type, (to search for an application) I want AHK to open the start menu so that I can utilize its search function
My rough outline for how I imagine it would work below - I've been trying to learn but got stuck here

```
Lwin::
Send, #{Tab}
if (""taskview is open"" + ""any char pressed"") {
Send, Rctrl + Esc
}
```

In the future I'd love to have the start button just appear on the Task View screen so that it's almost just like Gnome

Answer (score 0):

i wanted to do the same thing and got this so far, i like how this works tbh, but you might wanna add RWin as well (i don't have it, so i didn't)

before task view appears the start menu flashes shortly, but the activation timing keeps shortcuts working without opening task view, so it's a good tradeoff imo.

```
;couldn't check these names bc the names are different based on system language
;double click on the script in the task tray and hit CTRL+K to figure out the correct name
taskView := "Task View"     ;these 2 names are guesses
search := "Search"

;----------------------------------------------------------------------
;Hotkey function hotkeys have to be created first
Hotkey, ~*LButton, mousedown, off
Hotkey, ~*RButton, mousedown, off
Hotkey, ~*MButton, mousedown, off

Hotkey, ~LWin, showTask

;checks every half second if you're in task view to activate the key logging
SetTimer, taskInput, 500 
return

showTask:
    ;prevent repeats
    keywait, LWin
    ;cancel if a different key got pressed while win was held down
    if (A_PriorKey != "LWin") {
        return
    }

    if WinActive(taskView){
        sleep 1
        send {Esc}
        return
    }

    else send #{tab}

taskInput:
    if (!WinActive(taskView)){
        return
    }

    Mouse_Flag = 0
    Hotkey, ~*LButton, on
    Hotkey, ~*RButton, on
    Hotkey, ~*MButton, on

    ;wait for any key
    Input, key, L1 V, {VK0E}{LWin}{RWin}{Home}{End}{PgUp}{PgDn}{Del}{Ins}{BS}{Pause} ;excluded: {LControl}{RControl}{LAlt}{RAlt}{LShift}{RShift}{CapsLock}{NumLock}{PrintScreen}{Left}{Right}{Up}{Down}{AppsKey}{F1}{F2}{F3}{F4}{F5}{F6}{F7}{F8}{F9}{F10}{F11}{F12}
    
    if WinActive(taskView){ 
        if (key = LWin) { 
            keywait, LWin
            sleep 1
            send {Esc}
        }
        else if (Mouse_Flag || key = Chr(27)) { ;chr 27 = blank space character, matches some characters specified in the any key input check, notably Esc
            ;nothing/return
        }
        else {
            ;open search
            send #s
            WinWaitActive %search%
            if("LWin" != A_PriorKey && key != A_PriorKey){ ;slight fix if you type very fast and the letters get jumbled bc winwaitactive takes too long
                send {BS}
                send {%key%}
                send {%A_PriorKey%}
            }
            else send {%key%}
        }
    }
    Hotkey, ~*LButton, off
    Hotkey, ~*RButton, off
    Hotkey, ~*MButton, off
Return

mousedown:
    Mouse_Flag = 1
    sendevent, {Blind}{VK0E} ;unused virtual key
return
```